# Renting a car in Switzerland for short foreign trips

Tags: international-travel, car-rentals, switzerland

I like short trips because they are less problematic to plan than the long ones and still you can see a lot if you use a car.
Is it possible to rent a car in Switzerland for such a short trips, with necessary vignettes? (for example, for Austria)? How much does such service cost (I need really a small auto for myself only). Do you need a Swiss driver's licence to deserve such a pleasure, or the one from within EU is enough? 
Having a car in Switzerland can be expensive, so I'd like to know if it will be cheaper to rent a car when needed (I'll probably make one 2-4 days trip a month).

Answer (score 3):

Switzerland has car rental companies like any other country.

You only need a valid drivers license (from anywhere in the world), and a credit card.

Typical daily car rental cost in Europe is 70 to 100 Euro, but often cheaper on special offers. In Switzerland, everything is a bit more expensive, so I would not expect to get away under 100 SFR per day; again, if you are able to adjust your plans to special offers, you can get much lower prices.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "from anywhere in the world" is not true.

Comment: @mts AFAIK Switzerland does in fact accept any valid driver's license, although you may need a translation if it's not in English, French, German or Italian.

Comment: @jpatokal but does this also apply to rental companies?

Comment: @mts They get to make their own rules, but usually they're happy to let anybody drive as long as they have a license.